# UITableViewController without subclassing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to create and display a UITableView controller which allows the user to select an item and fire back a message to the delegate without subclassing it?

The reason is I just want to display a list of items in a popovercontroller and it seems a waste to have to create a subclass just for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view controller that presents the popover you could implement UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate - then set the popover's tableview to use the parent controller as its source and delegate before presenting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 5 SDK then you can make static cells.

Otherwise the only option is to create a subclass and provide a DataSource array.

Either ways you might want to have a View Controller that prepares the view controller loaded on the touch action?